# Meter comillas dobles al principio y final de un String DTO, para exportación CSV

Tags: java, regex, csv

Estoy intentando mediante DTO meter unas comillas dobles en el principio y final de un atributo String, para posteriormente escribirlo y exportarlo a CSV. Aquí un ejemplo del código a modificarlo:

```
final List<FullReportDTO> criteriaReport
final String enc = "ISO-8859-1";
final Charset charset = Charset.forName(enc);
OutputStream stream;

...

for (i = 0; i < nMaxExpedientes; i++) {
    final FullReportDTO e = criteriaReport.get(i);
...
    String subjectAux = (e.getSubject() == null) ? ""
                            : e.getSubject().replaceAll("\"", "..");
    final String subject = subjectAux;
    stream.write(subject.getBytes(charset));
```

Se agradecen todas las soluciones posibles. Saludos amorosos! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Modifica la línea que crea la variable `subjectAux` para incluir las
   comillas dobles.
2. Luego, escribe la variable `subjectAux` en el archivo CSV en lugar de `subject`

   ```
   final List<FullReportDTO> criteriaReport;
   final String enc = "ISO-8859-1";
   final Charset charset = Charset.forName(enc);
   OutputStream stream;

   // ...

   for (int i = 0; i < nMaxExpedientes; i++) {
       final FullReportDTO e = criteriaReport.get(i);

       // ...

       String subjectAux = (e.getSubject() == null) ? "\"\""
                     : "\"" + e.getSubject().replaceAll("\"", "..") + "\"";
       stream.write(subjectAux.getBytes(charset));

       // ...
   }
   ```

En este código, la variable `subjectAux` contiene el valor del atributo `subject` rodeado por comillas dobles y con la sustitución de comillas dobles por **".."**

Luego, se escribe el valor de `subjectAux` en el archivo CSV utilizando `stream.write()`.

Comment: Hola, @DevMind, muy buenas tardes! Te la compro, me parece la más factible. Muchas gracias! :)

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido mi respuesta. No olvides votarla y marcala como aceptada!